# How can I make a data frame from JSON files? (using downloaded JSON files from facebook)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, facebook

I'm very new to Python and currently undertaking a personal project using downloaded JSON files from Facebook, all from one chat on messenger. I keep getting an error saying df is not defined, despite me defining df.

I have multiple JSON files that I am trying to read into one dataframe. I created a loop so I could do this, with my defining the df within that loop. When I then call df to see it, it says its not defined. My code is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json, glob, os
import numpy as np

file_path = "work/Desktop/fb data/jsonmssg/message_1.json"

file_dir = "work/Desktop/fb data/jsonmssg"

json_pattern = os.path.join(file_dir, '*.json')

file_list = glob.glob(json_pattern)

dfs = []

for f in file_list:
    with open(file) as file:
        chat_history = json.loads(file.read()) 
        
        json_data = pd.json_normalize(chat_history['messages'])
        
        dfs.append(json_data)
        
        df = pd.concat(dfs)

       
df
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-00cf07b74dcd> in <module>
----> 1 df

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I tried creating a loop that would look through all JSON files in the same directory, expecting it would concatenate them into one dataframe. It didnt work.

Comment: Are you sure `file_list` is not empty? If it is empty, you'll never define your `df` variable.

Comment: I just checked and saw it is an empty list thanks! Thought I'd created a list with: json_pattern = os.path.join(file_dir, '*.json')

file_list = glob.glob(json_pattern). but it appears not. if you have any suggestions id be greatful!

Comment: Do you have folders in your *file_dir* directory?

Comment: I do, the file directory looks like this:                                                 
message_1.json,
message_2.json,
message_3.json,
message_4.json,
message_5.json,
message_6.json,
message_7.json,
message_8.json,
message_9.json,
message_10.json,
message_11.json,
message_12.json,
message_13.json,
message_14.json,
message_15.json,
message_16.json,
message_17.json,
Untitled1.ipynb. and these are all the files I am trying to make into one database. they all have the same layout (apart from Untitled1.ipynb is my jupyter notebook)

Comment: See my comments below as well as my answer. The problem is definitely that the file list is empty, but it shouldn't be. I don't know if "glob" is the issue (since you're not using "**" for a directory) or if the path separator is wrong (see answer from @PawelKam and my comment on that for more info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure glob is your best bet here. At the very least, it's not what I would have done... you only need glob to "**" directories.

How about:

```
import os
import fnmatch
import json
import pandas as pd

file_dir = "work/Desktop/fb data/jsonmssg"

json_file_list = [direntry.name for direntry in os.scandir("file_dir") if direntry.stat().size >0 and fnmatch.fnmatch(direntry.name, "*.json")]
for json_filename in json_file_list:
  deserialized = json.load(json_filename)
  if deserialized: // Will be null if json is invalid, I think
    df = pd.read_json(json_filename)
    df.to_string() // Just to prove it worked :)
```

Hope that helps simplify your life :)

Comment: Thankyou! i've tried this and it says: ValueError: Expected object or value. any ideas why?

Comment: @AliceCampbell I updated to show you how I would have accomplished the filename lookup. I'm not sure about glob... I think that's mostly useful for "folder/**/subfolder" type searches. I'm also not sure about os.path.combine with "*.xxx" unless you use os.path.abspath. See my comment on the other answer about glob for more details.

Comment: Oh wait... are you saying you tried this on one of the json files explicitly and it gave you a ValueError? That would normally mean bad JSON. Have you tried `deserialized = json.loads("full\path\to\message_1.json") just to ensure that it deserializes properly?

Comment: Hey, yes I think that's the issue !! It's facebook JSON data and I've heard it isn't very good quality. I'll try your suggestion, thanks :)

Comment: I added some error checking above, but yeah, I wouldn't expect Facebook to use valid JSON or valid anything else for that matter :D

Comment: One good way to see if it's valid JSON manually is to open it in Notepad++, go to Plugins -> Plugins Admin and enable JSTool (if you haven't already), and then go to Plugins -> JSTool -> JSFormat. This might allow you to see problems and fix them yourself, or determine how you can fix them programmatically :)

Comment: Also, if any of this is helpful, please upvote my answer and comments, and if you get ann answer that finally solves your problem be sure to mark it as the "best answer". We do this because we like to help, but the bonus points and badges make it more fun :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when trying to get a list of path names to files that are in different directories, including directories inside directories, you should use the `recursive` flag. I'm unsure if that is your case, though.

```py
glob.glob('mypath/**/*.json', recursive=True)
```

Secondly, because of the way you define your path, the pathname itself that you put into glob.glob() could be invalid. That's because different operating systems have different path name conventions, which could affect `os.path.join()`. For example, on my OS `os.path.join('work/Desktop/fb data/jsonmssg', '*.json')` results in `'work/Desktop/fb data/jsonmssg\\*.json'`. Note the incompatible `'/'` and `'\\'`.

You could relay on os.path.join() for building proper pathname for your OS. For example

```py
os.path.join('work', 'Desktop', 'fb data', 'jsonmssg', '*.json')
```

Before proceeding, be sure to check whether the path is correct with `os.path.exists(json_pattern)`.

Comment: I agree with this answer regarding the usage of glob. I wasn't aware that you could use "*.json" in os.path.join... gonna have to try that, if true it's handy.

Also, I believe that os.path.abspath(os.path.join("mypath/what/ever", "data.json")) will take care of that nastiness with the path separator. I user '/' in pathnames wherever possible despite the fact that I'm on Windows, because I think that  "//" is ugly ;) I also tend to use os.path.abspath, because I frequently log filenames and relpaths are not terribly useful in log files, and they always enter the logs as '/'.

Comment: Honestly, I always choose `pathlib` over `os.path`. I just wanted Alice to understand the error. Absolutepath seems like a good idea.

Comment: I always forget about `pathlib` but that would be a workable solution as well.

Comment: Thank you both! I'm now getting a different error after your suggestions. I tried running the code on a singular JSON file and it says 'ValueError: No objects to concatenate'. I believe the quality of the JSON file is rubbish cus its came from Facebook.

Comment: You can try reading the file as a json object per line with `pd.read_json('/path/to/file.json', lines=True)`.